# What does #{ } mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know that this may be a very basic question but i'm struggling to find a clear answer. What does using this, #{} , mean in Ruby? What does it do?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know why you asked this question. Basic Google will give you the information. Read [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings). Or here in Stacoverflow itself. See this [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bruby%5D+%22%23%7B%7D%22)

Comment: @ArupRakshit you can't google for `#{}`, can you?

Comment: Yea I couldn't google #{}. Thanks for everyone's help so quickly though :)

Comment: @James But before increasing the load in SO of such duplicate questions, you can search here itself..right ?

Comment: @Stefan Yes.. not lots of hits.. atleast 2 I got. see [this](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Ruby+%23%7B%7D&oq=Ruby+%23%7B%7D&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4078j0j8&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=121&ie=UTF-8#q=Ruby+syntax+%23%7B%7D).

Comment: If I don't know that it's called string interpolation and I got not results with my use of #{} in the question how can I search for it. Appreciate a little less condescension.

Comment: @James I found the question I linked serching here on SO for `[ruby] "#{}"`.

Comment: I tried and didn't find, sorry. But I really appreciate everyones help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is used for String interpolation: ( [wikipedia, ctrl+f "ruby"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation) )

```
apples = 4
puts "I have #{apples} apples"
# or
puts "I have %s apples" % apples
# or
puts "I have %{a} apples" % {a: apples}
```

The output will be:

```
I have 4 apples
```

---

[**String interpolation, Definition**:](http://ruby.about.com/od/sz/g/String-Interpolation.htm)

> In Ruby, string interpolation refers to the ability of double-quoted strings to execute Ruby code and replace portions of that strings (denoted by #{ ... }) with the evaluation of that Ruby code.
>
> It is the most common way to inject data (usually the value of a variable, but it can be the evaluation of any Ruby code) into the middle of a string.

---

**A thing to know:**

```
puts "This User name is #{User.create(username: 'Bobby')}!"
```

This will **make an implicit call** of `.to_s` on the User's instance object.

If you defined the method `.to_s` on the User model:

```
class User
  def to_s
    self.username
  end
```

It would output:

```
puts "This User name is #{User.create(username: 'Bobby')}"
# => "This User name is Bobby"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is for [String Interpolation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation).

In Ruby, there are three ways of interpolation, and `#{}` is just one way.

```
apples = 4
puts "I have #{apples} apples"
# or
puts "I have %s apples" % apples
# or
puts "I have %{a} apples" % {a: apples}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's called **String Interpolation**

In Ruby, string interpolation refers to the ability of [double-quoted strings](http://ruby.about.com/od/strings/a/String-Literals.htm) to execute Ruby code and replace portions of that strings (denoted by #{ ... }) with the evaluation of that Ruby code. It is the most common way to inject data (usually the value of a variable, but it can be the evaluation of any Ruby code) into the middle of a string.

```
print "What is your name? "
name = gets.chomp
puts "Hello, #{name}"
```

Note that any code can go inside the braces, not just [variable](http://ruby.about.com/od/beginningruby/a/variable.htm) names. Ruby will evaluate that code and whatever is returned it will attempt to insert it into the string. So you could just as easily say "Hello, #{gets.chomp}" and forget about the name variable. However, it's good practice not to put long expressions inside the braces.

Author: [Michael Morin](http://ruby.about.com/bio/Michael-Morin-44924.htm)

Comment: [If you're going to quote somebody, you have to attribute the quote to them.](http://ruby.about.com/od/sz/g/String-Interpolation.htm).

Comment: downvoted because you used somebody's definition without giving him the credits for it...

Comment: The time i wrote this there was 1.) No answers yet, 2.) I included several links to the Articles. Dunno why you would downvote that, but it's Ok i guess, your Choice of empowering SO.

Comment: Your answer still implies that you wrote the definition of String interpolation => That is why I downvoted, the fact that you included X links in your answer does not change anything because none of these links shows that you took the definition of Michael Morin!

Comment: Dude, I'm TOTALLY respecting other's work. I don't know how you take this as your Argument. I linked to TWO of his articles where someone can CLEARLY see that he is the Author. And you are "Thanking" me for putting the author SPECIALLY in my Answer, when your's don't even have it... Don't know whats wrong here.. Jeesus

Comment: @TheMiniJohn Be cool!! Enjoy your time with more answers and questions in SO... :-)

Answer (score 0):

That allows you to evaluate arbitrary ruby code within a string (double quotes only). So for example, in something like PHP you'd do

```
$my_var = "The value of a = " . $a;
```

But in ruby, you'd just do

```
my_var = "The value of a = #{a}"
```

This only works if the string is in double quotes, and NOT single quotes. If you us single quotes then you'll get the #{...} appear in the text

Answer (score 0):

You use it to represent a variable you want to print or puts out.  For example:

`puts "#{var}"` would puts out the value stored within your variable `var`.